# how to add Spinner while render a component on react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spinner, react-bootstrap

Suppose I will use the React Bootstrap spinner component. How can I show this component while rendering another component like app or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Install react-bootstrap and bootstrap via npm:

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

Call dependency in your component:

```
import Spinner from 'react-bootstrap/Spinner';
```

In your component function you can use this type of code:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => { // after some fake time, component will stop with render
        setIsLoading(false);
    }, 5000);
}, []);

return (
<>
    {!isLoading && <div>All components loaded.</div>}
    {isLoading && <Spinner animation="border" role="status">
        <span className="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
    </Spinner>
</>
)
```

On component render, it will show loading spinner for 5 seconds (5000 ms), and then it should show text: "All components loaded."

Comment: Initial isLoading should be true for your example otherwise It will never show Spinner

Comment: You're right. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Building off of user12475574's answer, another good option is to use `CircularProgress` from `@material-ui/core`:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { CircularProgress } from "@material-ui/core"

function MyComponent() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setIsLoading(false), 5000)
  }, [])

  return (
    {isLoading &&
      <CircularProgress color="primary"/>
    }
    {!isLoading &&
      <h2>Finished loading!</h2>
    }
  )
}
```

#### Result:

[image: Demo of spinner]

---

And if you want to show the exact progress, you can set its variant to `determinate`:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (progress < 100) {
      setTimeout(() => setProgress(progress + 1), 50);
    }
  }, [progress]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CircularProgress
        color="primary"
        variant="determinate"
        value={progress}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

#### Result:

[image: Demo of determinate spinner]